# Java: Palindrome Finding Taking Too Long; How to Optimize?

Tags: java

I've written a function to find whether a given string (stripped of spaces) is a palindrome.  Unfortunately, it takes too long to run.  Any ideas how I can make the below code run faster?  (I'm timing out on LeetCode's Online Judge):

```
public class Solution {

    public boolean checkIfPalindrome(String s) {
        if (s.length() == 0 || s.length() == 1) {
            return true;
        }
        //if first letter == last letter
        char first = s.charAt(0);
        char second = s.charAt(s.length() - 1);
        if (first == second) {
            String shorterString = s.substring(1, s.length() - 1);
            return isPalindrome(shorterString);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public String onlyCharacters(String s) {
        String toReturn = "";
        for (Character c : s.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
                toReturn += c;
            }
        }
        return toReturn;
    }

    public boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
        s = onlyCharacters(s);
        return checkIfPalindrome(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: The actual LeetCode OJ question specifies that the case is unimportant and that digits are allowed.

Comment: In Java there is no Function, it has methods only.

Comment: What will be  the optimum code for checking palindrome number?

Answer (score 4):

This isn't the most optimal way of finding if a `string` is palindrome or not.

Just loop through `n/2` iterations (where `n` is length of `string`) and check if character at position `i` is equal to character at position `n-i`

Answer (score 1):

If the length of the string `s` is `n` then `s` will be a palindrome if

```
s[i]=s[n-1-i] for i in range [0,ceil(n/2)]  // 0 based index
```

Code:

```
public static boolean checkIfPalindrome(String s) {
    for(int i=0;i<s.length()/2;i++) {
        if(s.charAt(i)!=s.charAt(s.length()-i-1)) {
            return false;
        }
    }   
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an algorithm method called "divide and conquer". But in this case is just to make it n/2 instead of n.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suitable algorithm that might just help :

1.For `i = 1 to n/2`

2.If `string[i] = string[n-1]` then `continue` in the loop

3.Else `break` and `return false`

4.`return true`

Answer (score 0):

You may use this `StringBuilder.reverse()` to check Palindrome:

```
    private boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
       StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder(str);
       return str.equals(strBuilder.reverse().toString());
    }
```

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer.

Comment: It was a) replaced by StringBuilder more than ten years ago, b) The Javadoc for StringBuffer suggests you do so, c) it was never a good choice for multi-threading anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If n is the length of the input string, your code takes O(n^2) operations. This may surprise you because there are no nested loops in your code, but both the substring method and the += operator for Strings require the creation of a new String, which requires copying its contents.

To see this in action, I have inserted

```
System.out.println(s);
```

into the `isPalindrome()` and `checkIfPalindrome()` methods, and invoked

```
isPalindrome("doc, note: i dissent. a fast never prevents a fatness. i diet on cod");
```

This produces the following output:

```
docnoteidissentafastneverpreventsafatnessidietoncod
ocnoteidissentafastneverpreventsafatnessidietonco
ocnoteidissentafastneverpreventsafatnessidietonco
cnoteidissentafastneverpreventsafatnessidietonc
cnoteidissentafastneverpreventsafatnessidietonc
noteidissentafastneverpreventsafatnessidieton
noteidissentafastneverpreventsafatnessidieton
oteidissentafastneverpreventsafatnessidieto
oteidissentafastneverpreventsafatnessidieto
teidissentafastneverpreventsafatnessidiet
teidissentafastneverpreventsafatnessidiet
eidissentafastneverpreventsafatnessidie
eidissentafastneverpreventsafatnessidie
idissentafastneverpreventsafatnessidi
idissentafastneverpreventsafatnessidi
dissentafastneverpreventsafatnessid
dissentafastneverpreventsafatnessid
issentafastneverpreventsafatnessi
issentafastneverpreventsafatnessi
ssentafastneverpreventsafatness
ssentafastneverpreventsafatness
sentafastneverpreventsafatnes
sentafastneverpreventsafatnes
entafastneverpreventsafatne
entafastneverpreventsafatne
ntafastneverpreventsafatn
ntafastneverpreventsafatn
tafastneverpreventsafat
tafastneverpreventsafat
afastneverpreventsafa
afastneverpreventsafa
fastneverpreventsaf
fastneverpreventsaf
astneverpreventsa
astneverpreventsa
stneverprevents
stneverprevents
tneverprevent
tneverprevent
neverpreven
neverpreven
everpreve
everpreve
verprev
verprev
erpre
erpre
rpr
rpr
p
p
```

That's quite a wall of text we are asking the computer to compute! We also see that every String is created twice. That's because you needlessly invoke onlyCharacters() in every iteration.

To avoid creating intermediary String instances, you can use a String Builder:

```
String onlyCharacters(String s) {
    StringBuilder toReturn = new StringBuilder();
    for (Character c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
            toReturn.append(c);
        }
    }
    return toReturn.toString();
}
```

Also, it turns out a StringBuilder has a cool method called reverse(), so we can simplify your program to:

```
boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    StringBuilder letters = new StringBuilder();
    for (Character c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
            letters.append(c);
        }
    }
    StringBuilder reversedLetters = new StringBuilder(letters).reverse();
    return onlyLetters.equals(reversedLetters);
}
```

This code only creates `2` StringBuilder objects rather than `n` Strings, and is therefore about `n/2` times faster than your code.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be faster than any other answer so far:

```
public class Solution {

  public boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    for (int low = 0, high = s.length() - 1;; low++, high--) {
      char cLow = 0, cHigh = 0;

      // Find the next acceptable character for the increasing index.
      while (low < high && !Character.isLetterOrDigit(cLow = s.charAt(low))) {
        low++;
      }

      // Find the previous acceptable character for the decreasing index.
      while (low < high && !Character.isLetterOrDigit(cHigh = s.charAt(high))) {
        high--;
      }

      if (low >= high) {
        // All previous character comparisons succeeded and we have a palindrome.
        return true;
      }

      if (Character.toUpperCase(cLow) != Character.toUpperCase(cHigh)) {
        // This is not a palindrome.
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You have only one object: your original `String`. Every character is tested until we get acceptable characters (`Character.isLetter`). Then only those are compared.

No temporary object, no superflous checks. Straight to the goal: it does one thing but does it well.

Note: this answers the actual Leetcode OJ answer by checking alphanumerics instead of only letters and by not caring about the case.